# wildcard subdomains in Wagtail

Tags: python, django, wildcard, wagtail

How can create subdomains in [Wagtail](https://wagtail.io/)?

I was looking at https://github.com/tkaemming/django-subdomains, but this uses the Django Site framework.

I have tried replacing

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
```

with

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Site
```

However wagtail has no attribute 'get_current'

What can I do? Is there a solution here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found answer, I use django  1.11 and wagtail 1.10

and django-subdomain 2.1.0

At this time django-subdomain not support django 1.10>=  so we need to 
Update the middleware to be compatible with Django 1.10

i just change

```
class SubdomainMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
```

in middleware.py  to

```
try:
   from django.utils.deprecation import MiddlewareMixin
except ImportError:
   MiddlewareMixin = object

class SubdomainMiddleware(MiddlewareMixin):
```

django-subdomain use django-site but wagtail use wagtail-site
so  i change utils.py file

from

```
def current_site_domain():
    from django.contrib.sites.models import Site
    domain = Site.objects.get_current().domain
```

to

```
def current_site_domain():
    try :
        from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Site
        domain = Site.objects.get(is_default_site=True).hostname
    except:
        domain = "127.0.0.1"
```

you can get site domain with many way

now django-subdomain  work with wagtail
just use http://django-subdomains.readthedocs.io/en/latest/  for Configuration

sry for my very bad english

Answer (score 1):

For wildcard subdomains you have to configure your web server (nginx, apache, etc). For NGINX you have to add

```
server {
....
server_name *.mydomain.com;
....
}
```

For Apache

```
ServerAlias *.example.com
```

in your *your-site.com.conf* file.

Comment: hi tnx   but i dont want multi-site   i need wildcard-subdomain  i want to change site.com/cat/{slug_url} to  {slug_url}.site.com

sry for my bad english  i found answer

Comment: @MajidBabaie if you've found the answer you can put here, on site, maybe will help others too.